# Adding multiple rows conditonally in R data frame (loop)

Tags: r, loops, row

I have trouble with adding multiple rows into a data frame under a certain condition.

My data set looks something like this:

```
ID TIME DV
1   0.5 1
1   2   2.3
1   30  0.02
1   35  0.01
2   0.4 0.9
2   2   2.8
2   30  0.01
```

Now I want to add rows for several IDs under the conditon TIME >30.

The output should look like this

```
ID TIME DV
1   0.5 1
1   2   2.3
1   30  0.02
1   35  0.01
1   100 0
2   0.4 0.9
2   2   2.8
2   30  0.01
```

I have tried the following code:

`cond  <- data2[data2$TIME > 30,]
cond_1 <- rownames(cond) 
for(i in cond_1){data2 <- rbind(data2[1:i,],newrow,data2[-(1:i),])}`

which works for the first insertion, but since the row numbers change with every addition of a new row it does not work for the rest.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to work around this problem and the data set is to large to do it manually...

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: Can you also post the expected output based on the input data? Thanks.  Based on the input, there are no rows that satisfy the condition.  Therefore, the output would be the same dataset, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The output should be the same dataset. Ideally I would like to add a row with the same information as the row before only with the TIME data item set to 100  (i changed my original post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(data2)
 rbind(data2, data2[, .SD[TIME>30] , ID] [, 2:3 := NA])
```

Comment: Thank you very much , the data.table package solved the problem quite well